# How to create several Websites with one Core-Layer created in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

i'm going to create a web-application with several Website-Portals using the same Core Module and some other small Modules. 
Currently i have about 5 "MainModules" which creating the Frontend of the 5 Websites and other stuff. Loading titles & layouts only in the specific MainModule is no problem, i've found some tutorials about this at akrabat.com.
But i have a problem with injecting or changing the current config. For example the navigation is in the config but if the whole application is loaded, ZF2 merges all config-arrays to one. It's fine but i want to set config-params especially only for the current MainModule/Namespace.

Is it anyhow possible to get the current namespace at getConfig-Method at the Module.php? How can i "set" config to change it for eg in module.php?
Is there any known tutorial about this topic? I didn't find anything about it. I've just made it at Symfony Framework 1.x years ago.
Would be great if any can give me a hint, a link or knows a tutorial or example about this topic!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the ZF2 library in you php.ini file
ex:

```
include_path = "../path/to/your/zf2/lib/ZF2"  
# set environment variable
zf2_path = "../path/to/your/zf2/lib/ZF2"
```

in init_autoloader.php

```
if (is_dir('vendor/ZF2/library')) {
    $zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';
} elseif (getenv('ZF2_PATH')) {      
    $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
} elseif (get_cfg_var('zf2_path')) { // Support for zf2_path directive value
    $zf2Path = get_cfg_var('zf2_path');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't mean to use one ZF2 lib for several websites, especially i'm using Zendserver. I want to create several webportals from one major business and datalayer.

Comment: One of the solutions is to use a REST, so you can make API calls to you main domain. using REST will allow you to pull/edit/delete/add and using on core. http://hounddog.github.io/blog/getting-started-with-rest-and-zend-framework-2/. check the PhlyRestfully module (ZF2 module for creating RESTful JSON APIs using HAL and API-Problem)